# SQL statement order by issue

Tags: mysql, sql

I run a select statement for a table. I do an ORDER BY on a field which is DATE type.
That field has 3 possible values:

1. A date>=today
2. A date<today
3. null

I wanted it to consider no2 as null in order to bring me the no1 results first and then ALL the others, no matter their values as I run a second ORDER BY next.
I tried anything with no success, it seems this is beyond my knowledge.
Thank you for reading me!

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: Yes, Im sorry I forgot mention this.
Its MySQL 5.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For SQL Server:

```
order by 
case when mydate >= getdate() then mydate else null end
```

Comment: I forgot to mention that Im using MySQL 5.1
Thank you for your answer.

Comment: @Babylon In MySQL `ORDER BY CASE WHEN mydate >= CURDATE() THEN 0 ELSE 1 END, othercol1, othercol2` Zeros sort before ones.

Comment: This almost worked.
Im saying almost because for a strange reason instead of fetching me the last 30 records Im asking (using LIMIT 0,30 in addition with the DESC in the ORDER BY) it includes a record which it supposed not to be in the last 30 and throws away one record which should be normally included in them!

Answer (score 0):

You can write an ORDER BY with CASE statement in mysql as well, or you can also write a CASE statement in SELECT clause with an alias and use that in order by. I can't understand what you actually want, if you can throw some sample data then we might be able to help you with the query itself.